# SQL, Inner join, replacing id with name

Tags: mysql

I am making a distributed system that is like Twitter where users can follow other users. I am using a mysql server database to store the data.

The tables that I have are:

- User (id, name)
- Follower (id, followerId)
- Timeline (id, timeStamp, content)

I would like to get a list of followers for a certain id. The statement that I am trying to use is `SELECT name FROM Follower INNER JOIN User USING(id) WHERE Follower.id = <some_id>`

That is, I would like all names of all followers for some id. The above is a syntax error, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Which part of my statement is incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an incomplete SQL statement, the `ON` clause on `JOIN` seems missing, try this:

```
SELECT User.name FROM Follower
INNER JOIN User ON User.id=Follower.followerId
WHERE Follower.id = <some_id>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select U.name from User U  
inner join  Follower F on U.id=F.followerId
Where F.id=<some_id>
```

You can also get other respective field